# javascript random numbers make the chance bigger to get some values

Tags: javascript, random

i've made some kind of encode function that uses an array with 62 characters (a-z,A-Z,0-9)
then i use a random number to access one of these.
but if i use it, it returns way to much letters and i want as much letters as numbers (which is also logical since the chance on a number is 10/62 versus 50/62)
could someone tell me some function that generates a random number but that has a higher chance to get a value between 52-62 then a value below 52.

Comment: how much "higher chance"

Comment: they must have like an equal chance 50/50

Comment: What you are looking for is a weighted random number generator.  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/weighrandom2.shtml has one way to do this.

Comment: that's the thing i need thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives you a 50/50 chance of getting a digit:

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var digits = "0123456789";

function getRandomChar() {
  var r = Math.random();
  return r < 0.5 ? letters.charAt(Math.floor(r*letters.length*2)) : digits.charAt(Math.floor((r-0.5)*digits.length*2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get random value between for example 0..100 but with a higher chance to happen in 50..60 you should add a second random function into equation:

```
var rnd = Math.round(Math.random()*( 100 - 50 ) + Math.round(Math.random()*10));
```

In this case first random number is generated to be between 0 and 50, then it get's a chance to be higher until 60

In your case for 52-62 it should be like this:

```
var rnd = Math.round(Math.random()*( 52 ) + Math.round(Math.random()*10));
```

Comment: Would this not make the first 10 letters of the alphabet much less likely?

Comment: Yes, you increase the probability, however you state in your question: "... but that has a higher chance to get a value between 52-62 "

Comment: Don't use `Math.round(Math.random()*n)`. It produces random numbers from 0 to n, but you get 0 or n half as often as the other numbers. Use `Math.floor(Math.random()*n)`.

Comment: Also, this method will make it *less* likely to get a value between 52 and 62 (and less likely to get a value betwwen 0 and 9).

Comment: I understand for 0..9, but how it makes less likely to get a value between 52-62 ?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis: Think of two dice. It's least likely to get 1+1 or 6+6. The same applies for any two random numbers that you add.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRandomIndex(){
    // flip a coin... 50% chance the if occurs, 50% chance the else occurs
    if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0){
        // return the number random function, values 52 and up
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 52;
    }
    else{
        // return the character random function, values 0 to 51
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random())` is always 0.

Comment: @Guffa - Ah, you are correct, I've updated my answer to account for this. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

First choose between 0 and 1 (heads or tails), if it's one, use a separate function that only returns numbers. Otherwise return a letter with a separate function that only returns letters.